# Azure mobile service, The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am using azure mobile service, i am sending auth token with request. Get request is working from client, But when i am trying to hit POST request it's throwing exception "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed." event i am binding auth token with request. Here is my code:-

```
>      string result = string.Empty;
>                 request.ContentType = "application/json";
>                 request.Method = "POST";
>     
>                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestData))
>                 {
>                     UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
>                     byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(requestData);
>                     Task.Factory.FromAsync<System.IO.Stream>(request.BeginGetRequestStream,
> request.EndGetRequestStream, null).Result.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
>                 }
>     
>                 request.Headers["x-zumo-auth"] = auth_token;
>                 request.Headers["ZUMO-API-VERSION"] = "2.0.0";
>                 try
>                 {
>     
>                 
>                 WebResponse webResponse = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse,
> request.EndGetResponse, null).Result;
>                 using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
>                 {
>                     result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
>                 }
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception ex)
>                 {
>     
>                     throw;
>                 }
```

If anybody have any idea please share with me. I have tried the same request with Postman, that is working. Same way i am using for "Get" request.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell with the detail here - the URL you are POSTing to would be most useful! The server has been configured to return the 405 - probably because your table has that method disallowed, or your custom API does not have a post function defined.

Comment: You're making your job a lot harder by not using the Azure Mobile client SDKs. Is there a particular reason you are making REST calls directly?  For information on the client SDK, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/

Answer (score 0):

That means, the server does not support `POST` requests for that url. Maybe you need `GET` or `PUT`. Does not have anything to do with authentication.